How to send data to GAS function?
I am using Google Apps Script to write a small web app where I can upload an image (Business Cards) which is then stored in my Google Drive.
The image should be utilized by ChatGPT which extract the information and save them into Google Spreadsheets.
I have this Index.html where I can select and image and upload it. It saved to my Google Drive successfully but I get an error Uncaught  at uploadImageToServer (Code:34).
Here is the HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      #status {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="uploadForm">
      <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*">
      <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadImage()">
    </form>
    <pre id="result"></pre>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <script>
      function uploadImage() {
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        const file = fileInput.files[0];
        const statusDiv = document.getElementById('status');

        if (!file) {
          alert("Please select a file before uploading.");
          return;
        }

        statusDiv.textContent = "Uploading image, please wait...";

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          const dataUrl = e.target.result;
          console.log("Data URL:", dataUrl);

          if (dataUrl) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
              document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);            
            }).uploadImageToServer(dataUrl);

            statusDiv.textContent = "Image uploaded successfully. Processing...";
          } else {
            console.error("Failed to generate Data URL.");
            statusDiv.textContent = "Error uploading image.";
          }
        };

        reader.onerror = function(error) {
          console.error("Error reading file:", error);
          statusDiv.textContent = "Error uploading image.";
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


I put a console.log and Data URL exists but it is somehow not pass to my GAS function uploadImageToServer().
Here is my Code.gs script
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function uploadImageToServer(dataUrl) {
  Logger.log("Upload function started");

  try {
    Logger.log("Received dataUrl: " + dataUrl);

    if (!dataUrl) {
      throw new Error("No dataUrl received");
    }

    const matches = dataUrl.match(/^data:(.+);base64,(.*)$/);
    if (!matches || matches.length !== 3) {
      throw new Error('Could not parse the data URL.');
    }

    const contentType = matches[1];
    const data = matches[2];
    const blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), contentType, "uploaded_image");

    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxx');
    const file = folder.createFile(blob);
    Logger.log("Image uploaded to Google Drive");

    const imageUrl = file.getUrl();
    Logger.log("Image URL: " + imageUrl);

    // Call Google Cloud Vision API
    const apiKey = 'xxx';
    const visionUrl = `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${apiKey}`;
    const image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob().getBytes();
    const encodedImage = Utilities.base64Encode(image);
    Logger.log("Encoded image for Vision API");

    const visionPayload = {
      requests: [
        {
          image: {
            content: encodedImage
          },
          features: [
            {
              type: "TEXT_DETECTION"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    const visionOptions = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      payload: JSON.stringify(visionPayload)
    };

    const visionResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(visionUrl, visionOptions);
    Logger.log("Vision API response received");

    const visionData = JSON.parse(visionResponse.getContentText());
    Logger.log("Vision API data parsed: " + JSON.stringify(visionData));

    if (!visionData.responses || !visionData.responses[0] || !visionData.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation) {
      throw new Error("No text found by Vision API");
    }

    const text = visionData.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text;
    Logger.log("Extracted text: " + text);

    // Call OpenAI API
    const openaiApiKey = 'xxx';
    const openaiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions';
    const prompt = `Extract the information from this business card text:\n\n${text}\n\nThe information should be in JSON format with keys 'Company', 'Name', 'Title', 'Phone', 'Website', 'Email', and 'Address'.`;

    const openaiPayload = {
      prompt: prompt,
      max_tokens: 150,
      n: 1,
      stop: null,
      temperature: 0.5
    };

    const openaiOptions = {
      method: 'post',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${openaiApiKey}`
      },
      payload: JSON.stringify(openaiPayload)
    };

    const openaiResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(openaiUrl, openaiOptions);
    Logger.log("OpenAI API response received");

    const openaiData = JSON.parse(openaiResponse.getContentText());
    Logger.log("OpenAI API data parsed: " + JSON.stringify(openaiData));

    const jsonResponse = openaiData.choices[0].text.trim();
    Logger.log("OpenAI response parsed: " + jsonResponse);

    const parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);

    if (!parsedData.Company || !parsedData.Name) {
      throw new Error("Parsed data incomplete");
    }
    
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    const row = [parsedData.Company, parsedData.Name, parsedData.Title, parsedData.Phone, parsedData.Website, parsedData.Email, parsedData.Address];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
    Logger.log("Data appended to Google Sheet");

    return parsedData;
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}

Here is the Execution Log when I run this code










12:37:37 AM
Notice
Execution started


12:37:06 AM
Info
Upload function started


12:37:06 AM
Info
Received dataUrl: undefined


12:37:06 AM
Info
Error: No dataUrl received


12:37:37 AM
Error
Error: No dataUrl receiveduploadImageToServer @ Code.gs:12



Here is the Google Spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mm85k4oEH_ycuDlU4wPPMG9zVuVWZyKdvRhkwyHphcY/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Here is the Script (I removed unnecessary code)
https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1zwAn-ycrb8s8nB2_sGlriWKQhVn0Sr5is29bo6OgtTVZr7dGHdiKA8u1/edit
and here the test web app
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz_1JbJWc2BpjrL5kV_m9h1UOn3c7X1vEntMeijF8SUXPEpl5unD9CceLu_XWfbHS-lwA/exec

Please create an [mcve] instead of the whole code. It looks that you should focus on the part that reads an image from Google Drive and pass it to the Vision API.

Regarding the execution logs, it looks that the problem is that you are running uploadImageToServer from the script editor. If you want to test this function you should mock the object assigned to the dataURL. IMO, the question is too broad. I suggest you to focus on the first error, then, if you like so, ask a second question about the execution logs.

I edit my post. I think the error is in the HTML in the line google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) ? Anyway I provided information and a minimal reproducible example

While the links might be helpful, questions on this site should be specific (ideally concise) and self-contained. As suggested in my first comment, please focus the question on one problem (running the server-side code from the web app or from the editor) and add a [mcve] corresponding to the chosen problem.
